# Compute difference between weekly values b country

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to find out what is the excess death (defined as the difference between deaths that occurred  in a specific week) / country

my table looks something like this:

```
Country Dates Death_in_2020 Death_in_2021

Germany 01.01 1700          1800

Germany 01.08 1800          1900

Finland 01.06 1346          1448

Finland 08.06 1444          1555
```

My first idea was to sort the data frame by date and country.

Comment: Will you please add a sample of your expected output?

Comment: Show your working till now

Comment: the expected output would be a column called excess death (excess death = death value of week1 Dec 2011 - death value of week 1 Dec 2010). The data ranges from 2010-to 2021. I am looking for all possible excesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to subtract values in one column from another column, you can do so like this:

```py
df['Excess_Death'] = df['Death_in_2021'] - df['Death_in_2020']
```

Comment: I really overcomplicated this in my head... thank you :)

Comment: @morvaybalazs Sure thing! Mind accepting the answer if it fixed the problem for you?